# Match index of first dataframe to column of a second dataframe and replace the index with corresponding values in the second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

'ref' is an AnnData object and one of its components is a `ref.var` Pandas dataframe.
`gene_list` is a separate Pandas dataframe with two columns: `ensembl_gene_id` and `hgnc_symbol`.
If `ref.var.index` matches `gene_list[hgnc_symbol]`, replace `ref.var.index` with `gene_list[ensembl_gene_id]`.
Ignore if no matches are found.
`ref.var_names` refer to the index of `ref.var`.

```
ref_column_name = 'features'  
for index, row in gene_list.iterrows():
    # Check if the 'hgnc_symbol' is present in the index
    if row['hgnc_symbol'] in ref.var.index:
        # Replace the value in the index with 'ensembl_gene_id'
        ref.var.index = ref.var.index.set_value(row['hgnc_symbol'], row['ensembl_gene_id'])
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [25], in <cell line: 2>()
      2 for index, row in gene_list.iterrows():
      3     # Check if the 'hgnc_symbol' is present in the index
      4     if row['hgnc_symbol'] in ref.var.index:
      5         # Replace the value in the index with 'ensembl_gene_id'
----> 6         ref.var.index = ref.var.index.set_value(row['hgnc_symbol'], row['ensembl_gene_id'])

TypeError: set_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

Input:

`ref.var`

```
pd.DataFrame({'features': {'A1BG': 'A1BG',
  'A1BG-AS1': 'A1BG-AS1',
  'A1CF': 'A1CF',
  'A2M': 'A2M',
  'A2M-AS1': 'A2M-AS1'}})
```

`gene_list`

```
pd.DataFrame({'ensembl_gene_id': {1: 'ENSG00000148584',
  2: 'ENSG00000175899',
  3: 'ENSG00000183044',
  4: 'ENSG00000165029',
  5: 'ENSG00000154263'},
 'hgnc_symbol': {1: 'A1CF', 2: 'A2M', 3: 'ABAT', 4: 'ABCA1', 5: 'ABCA10'}})
```

`ref.var_names`

```
Index(['A1BG-AS1', 'A1CF', 'A2M', 'A2M-AS1'], dtype='object')
```

Expected output:

`ref.var`

```
pd.DataFrame({'features': {'ENSG00000148584': 'A1CF',
  'ENSG00000175899': 'A2M'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` on the left index and the right `hgnc_symbol`

```
out = ref.var.merge(gene_list,left_index=True,right_on='hgnc_symbol')
    .drop('hgnc_symbol',axis=1)
    .set_index('ensembl_gene_id')
```